# Tunning my dash board linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have the following linq query insde my asp.net mvc web application , which mainly build our dash board, by displaying count() for many entities:-

```
public SystemInformation GetSystemInfo(int pagesize) 

        {
            var d = DateTime.Today;
            string[] notservers = new string[] { "vmware virtual platform", "storage device", "router", "switch", "firewall" };
            string[] types = new String[] { "server", "workstation" };

            var tmpCustomCount = tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => (int?)a.Quantity);
            SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()
            {

            AssetCount = new AssetCount() {

                CustomerCount = entities.AccountDefinitions.Count(),
                RackCount = tms.TMSRacks.Count(),
                ServerCount =  tms.TMSServers.Count(),
                VirtualMachineCount =  tms.TMSVirtualMachines.Count(),
                StorageDeviceCount =  tms.TMSStorageDevices.Count(),
                FirewallCount = tms.TMSFirewalls.Count(),
                SwitchCount =  tms.TMSSwitches.Count(),
                RouterCount =  tms.TMsRouters.Count(),
                DataCenterCount =  tms.DataCenters.Count(),
                CustomCount = tmpCustomCount == null ? 0 : tmpCustomCount.Value
                //tms.CustomAssets==null? 0 : tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => a.Quantity)

            },

           AdminAudit = AllIncludingAdminAudit("", auditinfo => auditinfo.SecurityTaskType, auditinfo2 => auditinfo2.AuditAction).OrderByDescending(a => a.DateTimeStart)
           .Take(pagesize).ToList(),
           LatestTechnology = tms.Technologies.Where(a=> !a.IsDeleted && a.IsCompleted).OrderByDescending(a => a.TechnologyID).Take(pagesize).ToList(),
           IT360ServerNo =     entities.Resources
            .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && (a.SystemInfo.ISSERVER == true ) && !(notservers.Contains(a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().ToLower()))).Count(),
            IT360VMNo = entities.Resources
            .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && (a.SystemInfo.ISSERVER == true) && a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().Equals("VMware Virtual Platform", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count(),
            IT360SDNo = entities.Resources
           .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().Equals("Storage Device", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count(),
            IT360SwitchNo = entities.Resources
            .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().Equals("Switch", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count(),
            IT360FirewallNo = entities.Resources
           .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().Equals("Firewall", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count(),
            IT360RouterNo = entities.Resources
           .Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && a.SystemInfo.MODEL.Trim().Equals("Router", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count(),

            DeleteNo = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a => ( EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd) == d && a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "delete" && a.TechnologyID != null)).Count(),//TechnologyId != null so that only assets that have tags will be included in the count
            CreateNo = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd) == d && a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "add" && a.TechnologyID != null)).Count(),
            EditNo = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd) == d && a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "Edit" && a.TechnologyID != null)).Count(),
            OtherNo = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd) == d 
                && 
               !((a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "delete" && a.TechnologyID != null) 
               || (a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "add" && a.TechnologyID != null) 
               || (a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower() == "edit" && a.TechnologyID != null)))).Count(),


            };
            return s;
        }
```

And the model class is :-

```
public class SystemInformation
    {
        public AssetCount AssetCount { get; set; }
        public  IPagedList<TechnologyAudit> TechnologyAudit { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AdminAudit> AdminAudit { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Technology> LatestTechnology { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Server/s")]
        public int IT360ServerNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "VM/s")]
        public int IT360VMNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "SD/s")]
        public int IT360SDNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Switch/s")]
        public int IT360SwitchNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Firewall/s")]
        public int IT360FirewallNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Router/s")]
        public int IT360RouterNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Delete Opeartion/s")]
        public int DeleteNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Create Opeartion/s")]
        public int CreateNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Edit Opeartion/s")]
        public int EditNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Other Opeartion/s")]
        public int OtherNo { get; set; }

        public Double HourSpan { get; set; }
        public int RefreshInSeconds { get; set; }
    }
```

The above is functioning well, but the problem is that i am sending a separate query to the DB to populate each variable such as customercount, RackCount, ServerCount ,etc...
I know that having single query to build the above might not be possible, as i am retrieving count() from separate tables. But is there a way to join the Count() on the same table to a single query, i mean to use something such as GroupBy and return the count based on the where critical ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupBy could be used for calculating counts of groups with regard to specified key. In your example you use a lot of additional filtering after or before equaling to a string key. You may try with the following case, but in other cases it will be hard to apply GroupBy efficiently:

```
var ActionCounts = tms.TechnologyAudits.Where(a =>
    (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.DateTimeEnd) == d && a.TechnologyID != null))
    .GroupBy(a => a.AuditAction.Name.ToLower())
    .Select(g => new {
        Action = g.Key
        ItemCount = g.Count();
    }).ToLookup(a => a.Action);
```

How to integrate with your code:

```
var tmpCustomCount = tms.CustomAssets.Sum(a => (int?)a.Quantity);

[Insert here:]

        SystemInformation s = new SystemInformation()

...

DeleteNo = ActionCounts["delete"] == null ? 0 : ActionCounts["delete"].Single().ItemCount;
CreateNo = ActionCounts["add"] == null ? 0 : ActionsCount["add"].Single().ItemCount;
EditNo = ActionCounts["edit"] == null ? 0 : ActionsCount["edit"].Single().ItemCount;
```

Comment: but in this way i am going to retrieve all the data from the server when building the ActionGroup varialbe, while what i need is the count().

Comment: and what is the type for ActionCount ,, could it be a Var ??

Comment: and how i will get the values for the ActionCounts ??

Comment: you updated code worked well, but incase the TechnologyAudit, does not have action = delete (no one perform a delete operation), then ActionCounts["delete"].Single().ItemCount will always retun an exception . can you advice if there is a way to handle this ?